# Problems with rotation animation keys baking

Tags: animation, export, baking, graph-editor, axis

I have a problem with animation curves after animation baking and after animation export. So you can see before/after.

Before
[image]

After

[image]

It's rotation data. They're rotates on 180 degrees in X and Z-axis, and Y got to be symmetrical. It's happening after animation baking and animation export. What should i do to stay them as Before?
Thank's!

PS I found that it could be because of quaternions. But how can i fix it?

Before animation baking

[image]

After animation baking

[image]

Comment: how did you export?

Comment: anyway: fbx, alembic... It's happening after baking the camera animation. It looks the same but trajectory is change.

Comment: That's most likely a gimbal lock, Quaternions should prevent that, however I think FBX does not support quaternion rotation. If you switch in the editor and bake that again, does it fix the issue? If not, show me the axis values

Comment: Added to the topic

Comment: I think this issue qualifies for a bug report.

Comment: Thank you for your help and time Frederik! I've sent them this case.

Comment: Was this resolved somehow?